# How to enumerate a slice using the original indices?

Tags: swift, slice, enumerate

If I want to enumerate an array (say for a `map()` function where I would need to use the index of an element together with its value), I could use `enumerate()` function.  E.g.:

```
import Foundation

let array: [Double] = [1, 2, 3, 4]

let powersArray = array.enumerate().map() {
    pow($0.element, Double($0.index))
}

print("array == \(array)")
print("powersArray == \(powersArray)")

// array == [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
// powersArray == [1.0, 2.0, 9.0, 64.0] <- As expected
```

Now, if I want to use some sub-sequence from the array, I could use a `slice`, and it would allow me to use just the same indices as I would use in the original array (which is just what I want in case if I would use `subscript` accessor in a `for` loop).  E.g.:

```
let range = 1..<(array.count - 1)
let slice = array[range]
var powersSlice = [Double]()

for index in slice.indices {
    powersSlice.append(pow(slice[index], Double(index)))
}

print("powersSlice == \(powersSlice)")

// powersSlice == [2.0, 9.0] <- As expected
```

However, should I try to use `enumerate().map()` approach like I did with original array, then I get totally different behaviour.  Instead of `slice`'s range of indices I would get a new, 0-based range:

```
let powersSliceEnumerate = slice.enumerate().map() {
    pow($0.element, Double($0.index))
}

print("powersSliceEnumerate == \(powersSliceEnumerate)")

// powersSliceEnumerate == [1.0, 3.0] <- Not as expected
```

Question is whether there is a decent way (i.e. without manual adjustments using offsets, or something) to enumerate a slice using its own indices and not the auto-generated 0-based ones?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you can replace the for-loop with `let powersSlice = slice.indices.map { pow(slice[$0], Double($0)) }`

Comment: Thanks, @MartinR.  I will keep your suggestion in mind as a workaround better than just offsetting the `enumerate`-generated indices range.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`enumerate()` returns a sequence of `(n, elem)` pairs, where the `n`s are consecutive `Int`s starting at zero. This makes sense because it is
a protocol extension method for `SequenceType`, and an arbitrary sequence
does not necessarily have index associated with the elements.

You would get your expected result with

```
let powersSlice = slice.indices.map { pow(slice[$0], Double($0)) }
```

or

```
let powersSlice = zip(slice.indices, slice).map { pow($1, Double($0)) }
```

The latter approach could be generalized to a protocol extension
method for arbitrary collections:

```
extension CollectionType {
    func indexEnumerate() -> AnySequence<(index: Index, element: Generator.Element)> {
        return AnySequence(zip(indices, self))
    }
}
```

This returns a sequence of `(index, elem)` pairs where `index`
is an index of the collection and `elem` the corresponding element.
`AnySequence` is used to "hide" the specific type
`Zip2Sequence<RangeGenerator<Self.Index>, Self>` returned from `zip()`
from the caller.

Example:

```
let powersSliceEnumerate = slice.indexEnumerate().map() { pow($0.element, Double($0.index)) }
print("powersSliceEnumerate == \(powersSliceEnumerate)")
// powersSliceEnumerate == [2.0, 9.0]
```

---

**Update for Swift 3:**

```
extension Collection {
    func indexEnumerate() -> AnySequence<(Indices.Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element)> {
        return AnySequence(zip(indices, self))
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you.