# A correct and idiomatic way to iterate through a collection with index in Swift?

Tags: swift

I want to iterate over an arbitrary Swift collection and get both the element and its index.

Basically an alternative to:

```
for (idx, el) in collection.enumerate() {
    print("element at \(idx) is \(el)")
}
```

but that gives me real generic indexes, not just sequential integers starting at 0.

Of course, the solution is going to be a part of a generic function that accepts any kind of collection, otherwise the difference wouldn't be very important.

Is there a better way than a naïve loop like below?

```
var idx = collection.startIndex, endIdx = collection.endIndex
while idx < endIdx {
    let el = collection[idx]
    print("element at \(idx) is \(el)")
    idx = idx.successor()
}
```

Writing that seems fairly error-prone. I know I can turn that code into a snippet, but I'd like to find a more concise and more idiomatic solution if possible.

Comment: from my tests idx.dynamicType is Int but you say generic index am i missing something?

Comment: @AliKıran: It depends on the collection. Arrays have integer indices, but strings for example have a special String.CharacterView.Index type. Also the indices of a collection need not start at zero (e.g. array slices).

Comment: I hope that the linked-to "duplicate" solves your problem. Otherwise let me know and I'll reopen the question.

Comment: @MartinR thank you i get it i just misunderstood the question

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, the other question is more narrowly formulated but the answer is exactly correct. I think the answer to this one was better and more to the point, though. I'm not sure what the SO policy is for such cases; if it were left to my discretion, I'd leave both. Thank you!

Comment: @AndreyTarantsov: I have re-activated the answer and reopened the question.

Comment: @MartinR: Awesome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any collection the `indices` property returns a range of the valid
indices. To iterate over the indices and the corresponding elements
in parallel you can use `zip()`:

```
for (idx, el) in zip(collection.indices, collection) {
    print(idx, el)
}
```

Example for an array slice:

```
let a = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
let slice = a[2 ..< 5]

for (idx, el) in zip(slice.indices, slice) {
    print("element at \(idx) is \(el)")
}
```

Output:

```
element at 2 is c
element at 3 is d
element at 4 is e
```

You can define a custom extension method for that purpose
(taken from [How to enumerate a slice using the original indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32688798/how-to-enumerate-a-slice-using-the-original-indices/32693004#32693004)):

```
// Swift 2:
extension CollectionType {
    func indexEnumerate() -> AnySequence<(index: Index, element: Generator.Element)> {
        return AnySequence(zip(indices, self))
    }
}

// Swift 3:
extension Collection {
    func indexEnumerate() -> AnySequence<(Indices.Iterator.Element, Iterator.Element)> {
        return AnySequence(zip(indices, self))
    }
}
```

Example for a character view:

```
let chars = "az".characters
for (idx, el) in chars.indexEnumerate() {
    print("element at \(idx) is \(el)")
}
```

Output:

```
element at 0 is a
element at 1 is 
element at 3 is 
element at 7 is z
```

Comment: Why are the `chars` example's indices 0, 1, 3, 7 instead of 0, 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @dantiston: Because the string indices internally refer to UTF-16 code points. But you should not care about these numbers. If you use the proper methods (like advancedBy, distanceTo) to operate on indices, everything works as expected.