# How do you use .enumerated() with ForEach in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Here's a simple SwiftUI List that works as expected:

```
struct App: View {
  let items = Array(100...200)
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(items, id: \.self) { index, item in
        Text("Item \(item)")
      }
    }.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
  }
}
```

but when I try to enumerate items by replacing `items` with `items.enumerated()` I get these errors:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that '(offset: Int, element: Int)' conform to 'Hashable'
>
> Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'EnumeratedSequence<[Int]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

TL;DR

**Warning**: If you get in the habit of using `enumerated()` with `ForEach`, you may one day end up with `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION` or `Fatal error: Index out of bounds` exceptions. This is because not all collections have 0-based indexes.

A better default is to use `zip` instead:

```
ForEach(Array(zip(items.indices, items)), id: \.0) { index, item in
  // index and item are both safe to use here
}
```

---

The folks over at [Point-Free mentioned that it's not safe to rely on `enumerated()` with `ForEach` in production since not all collections are zero-index based](https://www.pointfree.co/episodes/ep100-a-tour-of-the-composable-architecture-part-1):

> This is technically not the most correct way to do this. It would be more correct, and more verbose, to zip the `todos` array with its indices collection. In this case we are safe because we are dealing with a simple 0-based index array, but if we were doing this in production we should probably `zip`-based approach.

Apple's documentation for the enumerated function mentions this as well:

```
    /// Returns a sequence of pairs (*n*, *x*), where *n* represents a
    /// consecutive integer starting at zero and *x* represents an element of
    /// the sequence.
    ///
    /// This example enumerates the characters of the string "Swift" and prints
    /// each character along with its place in the string.
    ///
    ///     for (n, c) in "Swift".enumerated() {
    ///         print("\(n): '\(c)'")
    ///     }
    ///     // Prints "0: 'S'"
    ///     // Prints "1: 'w'"
    ///     // Prints "2: 'i'"
    ///     // Prints "3: 'f'"
    ///     // Prints "4: 't'"
    ///
    /// When you enumerate a collection, the integer part of each pair is a counter
    /// for the enumeration, but is not necessarily the index of the paired value.
    /// These counters can be used as indices only in instances of zero-based,
    /// integer-indexed collections, such as `Array` and `ContiguousArray`. For
    /// other collections the counters may be out of range or of the wrong type
    /// to use as an index. To iterate over the elements of a collection with its
    /// indices, use the `zip(_:_:)` function.
    ///
    /// This example iterates over the indices and elements of a set, building a
    /// list consisting of indices of names with five or fewer letters.
    ///
    ///     let names: Set = ["Sofia", "Camilla", "Martina", "Mateo", "Nicolás"]
    ///     var shorterIndices: [Set<String>.Index] = []
    ///     for (i, name) in zip(names.indices, names) {
    ///         if name.count <= 5 {
    ///             shorterIndices.append(i)
    ///         }
    ///     }
    ///
    /// Now that the `shorterIndices` array holds the indices of the shorter
    /// names in the `names` set, you can use those indices to access elements in
    /// the set.
    ///
    ///     for i in shorterIndices {
    ///         print(names[i])
    ///     }
    ///     // Prints "Sofia"
    ///     // Prints "Mateo"
    ///
    /// - Returns: A sequence of pairs enumerating the sequence.
    ///
    /// - Complexity: O(1)
```

In your specific case `enumerated()` is fine to use since you are using a 0-based index array, however due to the details above, relying on `enumerated()` all the time can lead to non-obvious errors.

Take this snippet, for example:

```
ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, item in
  Button(item, action: { store.didTapItem(at: offset) })
}

// ...

class Store {

  var items: ArraySlice<String>

  func didTapItem(at index: Int) {
    print(items[index])
  }
}
```

First notice that we dodged a bullet with `Button(item...` since `enumerated()` has guaranteed that `item` can be accessed directly without causing an exception. However, if instead of `item` we used `items[offset]`, an exception could easily be raised.

Finally, the line `print(items[index])` can easily lead to an exception since the index (really the offset) can be out of bounds.

Therefore, a safer approach is to always use the `zip` method mentioned at the top of this post.

Another reason to prefer `zip` is that if you tried using the same code with a different Collection (e.g. Set) you could get the following syntax error when indexing into the type (`items[index]`):

> Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Set.Index'

By using the `zip` based approach, you can still index into the collection.

You could also [create an extension on collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693004/35690) if you plan on using it often.

---

You can test this all out in a Playground:

```
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

// MARK: - Array

let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
Array(array.enumerated()) // [(offset 0, element "a"), (offset 1, element "b"), (offset 2, element "c")]
Array(zip(array.indices, array)) // [(.0 0, .1 "a"), (.0 1, .1 "b"), (.0 2, .1 "c")]

let arrayView = Group {
  ForEach(Array(array.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, element in
    PrintView("offset: \(offset), element: \(element)")
    Text("value: \(array[offset])")
  }
//  offset: 0, element: a
//  offset: 1, element: b
//  offset: 2, element: c


  ForEach(Array(zip(array.indices, array)), id: \.0) { index, element in
    PrintView("index: \(index), element: \(element)")
    Text("value: \(array[index])")
  }
//  index: 0, element: a
//  index: 1, element: b
//  index: 2, element: c
}

// MARK: - Array Slice

let arraySlice = array[1...2] // ["b", "c"]
Array(arraySlice.enumerated()) // [(offset 0, element "b"), (offset 1, element "c")]
Array(zip(arraySlice.indices, arraySlice)) // [(.0 1, .1 "b"), (.0 2, .1 "c")]

// arraySlice[0] // ❌ EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION
arraySlice[1] // "b"
arraySlice[2] // "c"


let arraySliceView = Group {
  ForEach(Array(arraySlice.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, element in
    PrintView("offset: \(offset), element: \(element)")
    // Text("value: \(arraySlice[offset])") ❌ Fatal error: Index out of bounds
  }
//  offset: 0, element: b
//  offset: 1, element: c

  ForEach(Array(zip(arraySlice.indices, arraySlice)), id: \.0) { index, element in
    PrintView("index: \(index), element: \(element)")
    Text("value: \(arraySlice[index])")
  }
//  index: 1, element: b
//  index: 2, element: c
}

// MARK: - Set

let set: Set = ["a", "b", "c"]
Array(set.enumerated()) // [(offset 0, element "b"), (offset 1, element "c"), (offset 2, element "a")]
Array(zip(set.indices, set)) // [({…}, .1 "a"), ({…}, .1 "b"), ({…}, .1 "c")]

let setView = Group {
  ForEach(Array(set.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { offset, element in
    PrintView("offset: \(offset), element: \(element)")
    // Text("value: \(set[offset])") // ❌ Syntax error: Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Set<String>.Index'
  }
//  offset: 0, element: a
//  offset: 1, element: b
//  offset: 2, element: c


  ForEach(Array(zip(set.indices, set)), id: \.0) { index, element in
    PrintView("index: \(index), element: \(element)")
    Text("value: \(set[index])")
  }
//  index: Index(_variant: Swift.Set<Swift.String>.Index._Variant.native(Swift._HashTable.Index(bucket: Swift._HashTable.Bucket(offset: 0), age: -481854246))), element: a
//  index: Index(_variant: Swift.Set<Swift.String>.Index._Variant.native(Swift._HashTable.Index(bucket: Swift._HashTable.Bucket(offset: 2), age: -481854246))), element: b
//  index: Index(_variant: Swift.Set<Swift.String>.Index._Variant.native(Swift._HashTable.Index(bucket: Swift._HashTable.Bucket(offset: 3), age: -481854246))), element: c

}

// MARK: -

struct PrintView: View {
  init(_ string: String) {
    print(string)
    self.string = string
  }

  var string: String

  var body: some View {
    Text(string)
  }
}

let allViews = Group {
  arrayView
  arraySliceView
  setView
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(allViews)
```

Updates:

- Deleted the part that mentioned you can use `\.1` since Peacemoon points out this could cause problems. Also I'm pretty sure if your items conform to `Identifiable`, there's no point in using zip in the first place, you should be able to just do `ForEach(identifiableItems)`.

Comment: Be careful to follow `(You can also use id: \.1 if your items conform to Identifiable.)` . If you use `\.1`. the index seems to be wrong. For me it's always 1

Answer (score 44):

When you enumerate this collection, each element in the enumeration is a tuple of type:

```
 (offset: Int, element: Int)
```

so the id param should be changed from `id: \.self` to `id: \.element`.

```
ForEach(items.enumerated(), id: \.element) { ...
```

However after this change you'll still get the error:

> Referencing initializer 'init(_:id:content:)' on 'ForEach' requires that 'EnumeratedSequence<[Int]>' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'

because `ForEach` requires random access to the data, but an Enumeration only allows in-order access. To fix this, convert the enumeration to an array.

```
ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.element) { ...
```

Here's an extension you can use to make this a little easier:

```
extension Collection {
  func enumeratedArray() -> Array<(offset: Int, element: Self.Element)> {
    return Array(self.enumerated())
  }
}
```

and an example that can be run in a (macos) Xcode playground:

```
import AppKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

extension Collection {
  func enumeratedArray() -> Array<(offset: Int, element: Self.Element)> {
    return Array(self.enumerated())
  }
}

struct App: View {
  let items = 100...200
  var body: some View {
    List {
      ForEach(items.enumeratedArray(), id: \.element) { index, item in
        Text("\(index): Item \(item)")
      }
    }.frame(width: 200, height: 200)
  }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = NSHostingView(rootView: App())
```

Comment: I got the following error 
`Type '(offset: Int, element: ProductCategory)' cannot conform to 'Hashable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols`
I have made sure that my custom class `ProductCategory` conforms to hashable and can be looped with foreach normally. what am I missing?

Comment: If your array item has an id property, then in the id: argument of the ForEach, insert: id: \.element.id. You could also try \.element.self

Comment: **Warning:** Relying on `enumerated()` in production could lead to crashes with certain collection types. You should [use zip instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145650/35690).

Comment: @Senseful It only leads to crashes if you try to index into the collection using the offset. If you're only using the offset as the id in the `ForEach` (which is what most of my use cases are), then using `enumerated() is perfectly fine.

Comment: @PeterSchorn: Correct, in this (and in most cases) you're fine. However, if you refactor the code months later, you might accidentally use the index and it could lead to a crash. I prefer to write defensive code that doesn't require me to remember all this context.

Answer (score 16):

In most cases, you don't need to `enumerate` it as it's kind of slow.

```
struct App: View {
    let items = Array(100...200)
    var body: some View {
        List {
           ForEach(items.indices, id: \.self) { index in
               Text("Item \(self.items[index])")
           }
        }.id(items).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but can you elaborate on `enumerated` being slow? It's documented complexity is `O(1)`. Also this approach results in the indices being used as the id which works fine in this simple case, but doesn't work when you're re-ordering `Identifiable` objects in a List.

Comment: If you need to trigger the items change, just add the .id() for the list.

Comment: That can work in certain situations, but not if you want your changes to be properly animated.

Answer (score 15):

One of the Apple SwiftUI examples enumerated() is using inside Array, and then you can add offset to be id, which is unique when you make Array enumerated.

```
ForEach(Array(data.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, observation in
```

Comment: This is actually the best answer because then I don't have to make my struct conform to Identifiable. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to re-use @senseful's answer you can do it like this:

```
struct ForEachIndexed<Data, Item, Content: View>: View where Data: RandomAccessCollection<Item>, Data.Index: Hashable {
    private let sequence: Data
    private let content: (Data.Index, Item) -> Content

    init(_ sequence: Data, @ViewBuilder _ content: @escaping (Data.Index, Item) -> Content) {
        self.sequence = sequence
        self.content = content
    }

    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(zip(sequence.indices, sequence)), id: \.0) { index, item in
            self.content(index, item)
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it like so:

```
ForEachIndexed([11, 17, 31]) { index, item in
    Text("\(index): \(item)")
}
```