# Can't access array from JSON in for each loop

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

In my project I can't access the "Floor" to be used in for each loop. I need to count floors of a bulding in the loop.

```
// MARK: - UcmData
struct UcmData: Codable {
    let buildings: [Building]
}

// MARK: - Building
struct Building: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let title, subtitle, info, image: String
    let floor: [Floor]
}

// MARK: - Floor
struct Floor: Codable {
    let number: Int
    let title, subtitle, image: String
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation

struct NamJHerduView: View {
    let ucmData = Bundle.main.decode(UcmData.self, from: "ucm_data.json")

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< ucmData.) //here i need to count floors and use maybe where clause to filter just floors from a special building
```

Comment: Your data could contain many buildings. _Which_ building's floors do you want?

Comment: let's say it will be based on the id or title of the building, there are 6 buildings in my data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `Identifiable` conformance

```
struct Building: Codable, Identifiable {
```

Now you can loop through buildings

```
ForEach(ucmData.buildings) { building in
  Text("Number of floors in \(building.title): \(building.floors.count)")
}
```

If you also need to access the index in the loop, see this answer: [How do you use .enumerated() with ForEach in SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59295206/how-do-you-use-enumerated-with-foreach-in-swiftui)

Comment: Yes this is looping trough the building, I have that alredy, but I can't make it loop trough floors of a building selected for example in condition based on buildings id

Comment: Same concept, make it conform to `Identifiable` and loop through it.

Comment: I made Identifiabale Floor like this `struct Floor: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, number: Int` with the `id` parameter, but still error occurs at the end of VStack from my first post at the top that "the compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions"

Answer (score 0):

I think you may want to organize your data so that it is nested like this:

```
// MARK: - UcmData
struct UcmData: Codable {
    let buildings: [Building]

    // MARK: - Building
    struct Building: Codable {
        let id: Int
        let title, subtitle, info, image: String
        let floor: [Floor]

        // MARK: - Floor
        struct Floor: Codable {
            let number: Int
            let title, subtitle, image: String
        }
    }
}
```

Then each `building` will have a `floor` array.

Comment: Actually this makes no difference

Comment: Agree with @vadian, this did not helped unfortunately.