# Removing from array - Fatal error: Index out of range - SwiftUI Binding

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am trying to get my head around SwiftUI bindings. Here I display an array in a view and bind the values to the second view. In the second view I remove the data from the array.

However I get the following,

> Fatal error: Index out of range

I am not getting an error for `self.person.notes.remove(at: self.index)` in fact this is actually removing the note in the array. It must be in the first view when using `ForEach` as the array has been modified and now it is out of bounds. But I am unsure how to get around this ? Surely the `Binding` should have resolved this.

**View 1**

```
ForEach(self.person.notes.indices, id:\.self) { index in

   NoteView(person: self.$person, room: self.$home.notes[index], index: index)

}
```

**View 2**

```
@Binding var person: Person
@Binding var note: Note
var index: Int

if self.index > 0 {
       Button(action: {
             self.person.notes.remove(at: self.index)
       }) {
           Text("Remove")
       }
 }
```

Any idea how this is supposed to work in SwiftUI ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145650/1652402 is the solution that works for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing with a pre given index is always a risk. Possibility of data changing in background etc. Get the index at the time you try to remove the item to be sure to have the right one. In case the data changed somewhere else.
This should help you understand:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var myData: Array<String> = ["first", "second", "third"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.myData, id: \.self) { data in
            SecondView(myData: self.$myData, data: data)
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    
    @Binding var myData: Array<String>
    // the data that is being tied to the view
    var data: String
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Button(action: {
            // calculate the index at the time of removal
            if let index = self.myData.firstIndex(of: self.data) {
                self.myData.remove(at: index)
            }
        }) {
            Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(width: 100, height: 100).overlay(Text("Button \(self.data)"))
        }
        
    }
}
```

Produces this:

[image]

As you mentioned your error lies in the first view. This is most likely because you are building the ForEach with the number of indices. The moment you remove one, the ForEach runs into the error as it loses "track" of the item and the item with the index the ForEach provided does not exist anymore.
Try this:

```
ForEach(self.person.notes, id:\.self) { note in

   // Remove the index and calculate it on the second view as shown above. This then should solve the problem
   NoteView(person: self.$person, room: self.$home.notes)

}
```

Comment: I am not getting an error for 'self.person.notes.remove(at: self.index)' in fact this is actually removed the note in the array. It must be in the first view when using ForEach as the array has been modified and now it is out of bounds

Comment: Ore how in this answer the first view doesn't refer to the index. That is the change you need to make.  @Simon, your answer could be improved by showing the OP's code with the required changes.

Comment: I added explanation for the question. I'm sorry for not answering straight ahead. I usually tend to give the idea of how to solve issues rather than just providing the exactly needed code. As I think its more important to understand rather than just copy working code.

Comment: @Simon Thank you, I will accept this answer and I kind of figured this after you answered; I just got stuck somewhere else and forgot to reward sorry. - when changing the code from using Indices the view no longer updates when I add the the list, so I went further by using an ObservableObject rather than a state and binding, currently testing the different behaviours using different methods of managing states.

Comment: The View should always update when using @State and it changes.

Comment: @JSK first comment was helped me