How do I get items added to MyList to have Alternating background colors
I originally had alternating row backgrounds on the list when that didn't work I tried putting it on the rows which also did not work.  I've tried other methods such as using % mod operator to select a specific color which also did not work.  Alternating row backgrounds initially works with an empty list.  The added items remove the alternate colors.
struct MyList<Content>: View where Content: View {
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    var body: some View {
        List { content( )
            .alternatingRowBackgrounds( )
        }
        .listStyle( .bordered )
//      .cornerRadius(10)
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .alternatingRowBackgrounds( )
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
}

Edit - 1
I rewrote the above to accept a simple array of strings so you can see the issue:
func MyList(_ data: [String]) -> some View {
    let sortedData = data.sorted {
        $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedAscending
    }

    return List {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 2) {
            ForEach(sortedData, id: \.self) { curItem in
                    HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text( curItem )
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // Left-align the text
    .listStyle(.bordered)
    .padding(.vertical, 2)
    .alternatingRowBackgrounds()
    .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
    .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
}



you'd be better assigning a row background bool to each item of data in a computed property that gets passed into the List. And FYI whever you pass a viewBuilder param you must evaluate it in init, e.g. make an init, call content() and store the result as a let but usually its best to just use ViewModifier which handles this.

alternatingRowBackgrounds is only available on macOS.
macOS example code
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var arr = ["item-1","item-2","item-3","item-4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add item") {
                arr.append("item-\(arr.count+1)")
            }
            List(arr, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
            }
            .listStyle(.bordered)
            .alternatingRowBackgrounds()
            .padding(.vertical, 2)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
    }
}
 

For iOS17 you could try a different approach using enumerated and a listRowBackground
with condition.
iOS17 example code:
    struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var arr = ["item-1","item-2","item-3","item-4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add item") {
                arr.append("item-\(arr.count+1)")  
            }
            List(Array(arr.enumerated()), id: \.offset) { index, item in
                Text(item)
                    .listRowBackground(index % 2 == 0 ? Color.blue : Color.yellow)
            }
            .listStyle(.plain)
            .padding(.vertical, 2)
            .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
            .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
        }
    }
}

You could try this using your MyList construct:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var arr = ["item-1","item-2","item-3","item-4"]
    
    var body: some View {
        MyList(arr)
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func MyList(_ data: [String]) -> some View {
        let sortedData = data.sorted {
            $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == .orderedAscending
        }
        List(sortedData, id: \.self) { curItem in
            LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())], spacing: 2) {
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text( curItem )
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading) // Left-align the text
        .listStyle(.bordered)
        .padding(.vertical, 2)
        .alternatingRowBackgrounds()
        .listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())
        .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
    }
    
}


I've been using it on MacOS.  Sorry to have forgotten to add that Info.  Your example works for me.  I swapped out your settings in MyList and the same issue happens so the only thing I can see that is different is that I'm using content in MyList and calling it with a grid but still don't see why that should matter.

I rewrote my code to use a different technique which shorts the same the same issue.  It's above in Edit 1.  This is simpler  as you can call it with a string list to make it easier to see the issue.   I also provided a screen shot of the issue.  Sorry I accidentally added the graphic to your answer.  I moved it to mine where it belongs.

updated my answer using your MyList construct, with modifications.

enumerated() has its issues https://stackoverflow.com/a/63145650/259521

@malhal, but clearly this is not an issue here with the string Array. As the Apple docs mention with enumeration,
"These counters can be used as indices only in instances of zero-based, integer-indexed collections, such as Array and ContiguousArray".

@workingdogsupportUkraine Terrific your last change (second example above)) fixed the issue.  You used the exact same list of properties I did but evidently the order is a bit sensitive.  In this case I wouldn't think the order should matter since the background should be drawn first that is why I put it in the back.  Great stuff TY!!

Sorry, when I left for the day I realized that I had not marked it.  When I came back I marked it immediately.  Thanks again.
